# CSS column bug fix or alternative

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

Due to Chrome (and other Blink browsers) having a bug where only the first 500 columns are painted i need either a fix/hack, or an alternative solution.

See bug here (there is 509 pages - not 500): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLxozK

```
/* codepen link must be accompanied by code */
column-width: 400px;
```

I parse EPUB html to a single file. The EPUB's styling must be preserved, so i can't change the html structure.

CSS columns does a good job of rendering such a flat document horizontally. But the 500 limit in Blink means blank pages in Android Webviews.

Is there any workaround for this bug?

Users can adjust font size etc meaning amount of columns can change. So an alternative solution must be able to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

What a cool little bug, I've never seen that before!

By the looks of things you'll need to add `display:none` to some of your `div`s. You'll need to use Javascript to see what's in view and see what's not. You'll get the added bonus of not using any system resources unnecessarily as you won't be painting any of the pages that aren't in view.